# Hide password in Genexus beforeConnect procedure

Tags: genexus

I'm using the BeforeConnect option in Genexus. I put this code in a procedure...

```
&UserID = &websession.Get("db")

//select the Database depending on websession 
Do Case
   Case &UserID = "1" 
        &DataBase  = "CambioDB1" 
   Case &UserID = "2" 
        &DataBase  = "CambioDB2" 
   Otherwise 
        &DataBase  = "CambioDB1" //default database 
EndCase

//Change connection properties 
&dbconn = GetDatastore("Default") 
&dbconn.UserName = 'username' 
&dbconn.UserPassword = 'password'
&dbconn.ConnectionData = "DATABASE=" + &DataBase.Trim() //SQLServer
```

... set the BeforeConnect property and it works.

But how can I avoid to put the password of the db in the code?
I was thinking to use a file to read from, but it would be an unencrypted password anyway.

How can I solve this? Is there a way to manage this or do I have to risk the password in clear text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nicola,

You may use the ConfigurationManager to read a value from the standard config file (client.cfg for Java, web.config for .net).

&MyPassword = ConfigurationManager.GetValue('MY_PASSWORD')

Add a value to your configuration file with the password.
For example:
MY_PASSWORD=my-db-password

You probably want to save the password encrypted for an extra layer of security.
Simple:
&EncPass = Encrypt64(&Password, &SysEncKey)

Stonger encryption:
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?42682,Symmetric+Stream+Encryption

&EncPass = &SymmetricStreamCipher.DoEncrypt(symmetricStreamAlgorithm, key, iv, plainText)

Comment: Is there a way to add data to the web config directly from Genexus or do I have to do it by hand?

I tried to save my unencrypted password in the file anyway and it works, but I don't understand how encryption works. I tried to recover the Connection-Default-Password but it's not in clear text and doesn't work as password. Encryption still needs a key somewhere, so I'm just shifting the problem. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your config file should be protected already, so encrypting information is not required. I would do it anyway, if only to add a layer of protection from someone gaining access to this file.  It is true that now you have to define where to store the key, which could be hardcoded in the program, or stored on the same config file. The person that gained access now has to know how to combine the key and encrypted password to the gain access to the database. That is harder than using just the password.

Comment: At the moment I'm trying to use twofish as genexus does to camouflage web config datas. I have anyway to store somewhere the key, but as you said is at least an extra step. I'd like to write these datas automatically in the web config but I doubt is doable. Thanks for your suggestions.